# Ayuda con error en git $ git fsck Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done. error: HEAD: invalid sha1

Tags: git

En mi práctica de git, resulta que me apareció esto en git:

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer 1a410efbd13591db07496601ebc7a059dd55cfe9
error: refs/heads/master: invalid sha1 pointer 1a410efbd13591db07496601ebc7a059dd55cfe9
error: refs/heads/masterecho: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
dangling blob 5cd9f67660ab7e2cd687598a3346e186ff28f634
```

¿Alguna idea o solución para este problema?

Comment: Ese error te apareció cuando aplicaste que comando?

Comment: Con este comando $ git log --pretty=oneline  master
fatal: bad object master

Comment: Ahora acabo de usar un comando: $ git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at 7919098 añade readme

Comment: Luego de aplicar ese comando, ahora hice git status $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        test/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: Este es el log: $ git log -g
commit b89a42a241afa99a3cbe76b43a9d946d19dba1a5
Reflog: HEAD@{0} (lourcastillo <xxx @gmail.com>)
Reflog message: commit: Se añade archivo test.txt
Author: lourcastillo <xxx @gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 12 12:59:21 2017 -0300

    Se añade archivo test.txt

commit 7919098121e46b24238f98b91f43bf93237b2136
Reflog: HEAD@{1} (lourcastillo <xxx @ gmail.com>)
Reflog message: reset: moving to origin/master
Author: lourcastillo <xxx @ gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 5 17:37:01 2017 -0300

    añade readme

Comment: $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: No comentes todo, edita tu pregunta y agrega los detalles que te faltaron
Y aún no se te entiende que es lo que preguntas, ejecutaste git lof --pretty=online? y te marco ese error o como es?

Comment: Mi error fue este: fatal: bad object HEAD
y la solución encontré con el comando: `git fetch origin`
`git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo ahí si no mal me equivoco es regresar prácticamente al origen del repositorio y no sé si sea lo mas conveniente, en todo caso responde a tu pregunta con tu respuesta y seleccionala como la indicada por si otro tiene la misma duda

Comment: Perfecto Sergio, muchas gracias! aunque no creo que sea una buena práctica para proyectos grandes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En todo caso, esta es la primera vez que empiezo a ver git, muchas gracias por sus ideas y/o sugerencias. Perdón por mi desorden en responder o crear el topic. Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Debes agregar la respuesta a tu pregunta acá. Modifica tu respuesta para que sea útil a los demás.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su comentario, ya edité la respuesta y espero que sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 1):

Mi error fue: `fatal: bad object HEAD` y la solución que encontré en el momento fue aplicar el comando: `git fetch origin` `git reset --hard origin/master`

¿Alguna idea o sugerencia mejor a esta práctica?